# TortoiseCVS checkout no password prompt

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

i'm feeling really stupid. I want to use TortoiseCVS to checkout a repository using pserver protocol. Using Eclipse, there is a password-field where I enter my PW and all works fine. In TortoiseCVS there is only a user field and no way to enter my password. Of course it fails because of an "empty password used" if I try to load modules or checkout.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it the only error message you see? If password is incorrect, it should ask for correct one. Check cvsroot again please.

Comment: @keltar: Yes this was the only error message and it did not ask me anywhere to enter a different one.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the answer. Simply type user:password into the user field.